# Regex Statement for capturing elements inside the outermost brackets

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am looking for a regex statement that I have already racked my brains over.
I want to give the following inputs:

**Input**

```
T_0-p(T_1-p(T_2,K_0),CW_0)
```

T_0, K_0 and CW_0 are elements. These elements always consists of word characters followed by _ and an integer. These elements are seperated to each other by an - or are inside the p() operator. Inside the p() operator the elements are divided by a comma. The occurrence of another p() or - inside a p() operator is also possible.

What i want is to have 2 regex statements to capture these elements. One for capturing the elements which are outside of any brackets. Currently i am using this one:

**Regex**

```
(?<![,\(])(?<s>\w+_\d)(?![,)])
```

This gives me :

**Capture**

`T_0`

This is working fine for me.

The other one is the one i am struggling with. This should capture whats inside the outermost p() operator and also what is seperated by commas.

So I could work with an output like this:

**Capture**

```
Capture 1 : T_1-p(T_2,K_0)
Capture 2 : CW_0
```

What i tried to do was this:

**Regex**

```
p\((?<p1>.+?),(?<p2>.+?)\)
```

But this obviously does not work, if you have another p() operator inside a p() operator. In order to do so, it need to be modified. It has to check that the capture has as many open bracket as enclosed ones.
Is there are way to do that with a regular expression? Can anyone help me with that? Or do you have another idea on how to accomplish that?

Sorry if there is an obvious way on doing that, i am new to regex.

I want to implement this with Julia. Julia has Perl-compatible regular expressions, as provided by the PCRE library.

Comment: This basically matches the same element as my this one does: `(?<![,\(])(?<s>\w+_\d)(?![,)])` right? Or is this just to match whats outside the parentheses and then form another statement to captures whats inside?

Comment: `(?<![,\(])(?<s>\w+_\d)(?![,)])` does NOT match your pattern outside parentheses. It [matches inside parentheses](https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/3), too.

Comment: Oh yes, you are totally right. Thats not supposed to happen! Thank you again!

Comment: So, did my suggested patterns work? Reminding my now deleted comment by wrong SO bots: To get the pattern matches outside parentheses, you need `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+_\d+`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/1). The second could probably be matched with `(?:\G(?!^),|p\()\K\w+_\d+(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)))?`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/2).

Comment: @lambcount - _Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._

Comment: Ah i already wondered where our first comments went. Your regex works in a way, that captures the desired elements, but in application i need it to capture everything thats seperated by a comma inside the outermost brackets. The the capture should look like `T_1-p(T_2,K_0)` and not only `T_2,K_0`. I do not understand your regex fully, but i will try to modify that way. 

Thank you alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these regexps:

```php
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+_\d+
(?:\G(?!^),|p\()(\w+_\d+(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))?)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/4).

*Regex #1 details*

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)` - a string between (potentially nested balanced) parentheses that is matched and the match is failed
- `|` - or
- `\w+_\d+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores, `_`, and then one or more digits.

You may add `(` and `)` around the `\w+_\d+` pattern if you need a group by all means. Note it will be Group 2.

*Regex #2 details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^),|p\()` - either the end of the previous match and a `,` char, or `p(`
- `(\w+_\d+(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))?)` - Group 1:

  - `\w+_\d+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores, `_`, and then one or more digits
  - `(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `-p`  - a `-p` string
    - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\))` - Group 2 (it must be here defined because we need to recurse the pattern): `(`, then zero or more occurrences of one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the Group 2 pattern recursed and then a `)` char.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help. Sorry i could not test it anytime sooner.

The _regex #1_ is working quite goo. The _regex #2_ has a problem if i give the following input: 
`T_1-p(T_2-T_3,T_4-T_5))`
i wouldve anticipated that the output would look like this: `group1 :T_2-T_3
group2: T_4-T_5`

But i only get the following output: `group1: T_2`
any suggestions on how to modify the current _regex #2_ ?

Comment: @lambcount Then try https://regex101.com/r/cjpofI/5, I replaed `_\d+` with `(?:-\w+)*`.

Comment: this works with the Input: `T_1-p(T_2-T_3,T_4-T_5))` but not for the input from the original question: `T_0-p(T_1-p(T_2,K_0),CW_0)` Here only the `T_1-p` gets matched. I tries modifying it, but i cant get it to work for both.

Comment: Ok, `(?:\G(?!^),|p\()(\w+(?:-(?!p\()\w+)*(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))?)`

Comment: This works exactly as i need it to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry that my tests before did not reveal this. But it seems like that your last regex: (?:\G(?!^),|p\()(\w+(?:-(?!p\()\w+)*(?:-p(\((?:[^()]++|(?2))*\)))?) does not work if i change this order inside the first p operator  or put the second p() right after the first one.  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5nFUV/2). 
How do i accomplish that?

Comment: @lambcount See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5nFUV/3). You are giving out too many examples without revealing the actual pattern requirements. I added a small "human readable" formulation of the problem in the regex fiddle.